# Set properties in multi-level mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

This is my schema:

```
var userschema = new mongoose.Schema({

  user: String,
  imagen: [{ 

              title: String,
              name: String,
              path: String,

           }]

});
```

And I'm trying this:

```
 usermodel.findOne({ user: req.session.user }, function(err, user){

     var img = user.imagen[user.imagen.length];

     img.title = req.body.title;

     user.save(function(err){

        if(err) { throw err; }

     });

 });
```

An the console returns `TypeError: Cannot set property 'title' of undefined`. So, I don't know why is undefined. I think I have to create a new array element, and then set the properties of that array element, but I don't no how. Any solution to this...?

Thank's advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's undefined because you've gone off the end of the `user.imagen` array.  It only has `user.imagen.length` elements so with JavaScript's 0-based array indexes the last element is at index `user.imagen.length-1`.

If you're trying to add a new element:

```
usermodel.findOne({ user: req.session.user }, function(err, user){
    user.imagen.push({ title: req.body.title });
    user.save(function(err){
        if(err) { throw err; }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such item in any array: `anyArray[anyArray.length]`.
You must use `anyArray[anyArray.length - 1]` i think.